# CSS Parent anchor tag's display on children anchor tags?

Tags: html, css

I have something like following

```
<a class="item" href="a.htm">
  <div class="title">abcd</div>
  <div class="body">abcd</div>
</a>
```

with the following style

```
a.item {
  display:block;
}
```

As soon as I add another anchor tag inside a.class,

```
<a class="item" href="a.htm">
  <div class="title">abcd</div>
  <div class="body">abcd</div>
  <a class="child" href="b.html">child</a>
</a>
```

even though I have

```
a.child {
  display:inline
}
```

it breaks the child into a separate block. How do I go around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot nest `<a>` elements. Replace either of the `<a>` with `<span>`. Since you've got two `href` attributes, I assume that you want the following effect:

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jE6Dm/

CSS:

```
a.item span {
  display:block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
  <a class="item" href="a.htm">
      <span class="title">abcd</span>
      <span class="body">abcd</span>
  </a>
  <a class="child" href="b.html">child</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

ericbae is right you cannot use  tag within a  tag. Other important thing you are applying  tag over a div, it may not work in Internet Explorer. SO be carefull.